# Car Insurance cover for travelling to work

Tags: car, insurance

Does anyone know if travelling to work used to be included in Social Domestic and Pleasure car insurance please.

Comment: Insurance question are country and maybe even state/province specific. Please specify your location.

Comment: The particular phrase is used in UK car insurance, but I agree we need asker to clarify.

Comment: Yeah. I have i.e. never heard of Social Dmoestic or Pleasure - and going to work is "normal social use" where I live, i.e. you are so to say taking your own car to work and back home. Also this may be insurance specific - so instead of asking US - ask either the insurance, or read the insurance documentation (which, I agree, is often quite a read).

Comment: By traveling to work, are you going to fixed place AKA an office or will you be going to different locations like a salesperson or an at-home nurse?

Answer (score 3):

In the UK, Social Domestic and Pleasure does not cover any form of driving for work.

If you want commuting to a fixed place of work, then make sure you add that to the policy.  Driving to several different sites is business travel, and so a different thing again.